# Linq query with negated condition in Any not returning the expected result

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> lista = new List<string>()
            {
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d",
            "e",
            "f"
            };

            lista.Where(l1 => Enum.GetNames(typeof(prova)).Any(l2 => l2.Equals(l1))).ToList().ForEach(l => Console.WriteLine(l));
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    public enum prova
    {
        a,
        b,
        c
    }
```

I'm using C# and EF

With

```
Any(l2 => l2.Equals(l1))
```

I get a,b,c in output

With

```
Any(l2 => !l2.Equals(l1))
```

I get a,b,c,d,e,f in output

I was expecting d,e,f

What is happening?

Comment: I don't see any Entity Framework being used here.

Comment: It does what you told it: for every element in the list there is at least one enum value that _does not equal_ that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, just negate your where condition. Try this.

```
 lista.Where(l1 => !Enum.GetNames(typeof(prova)).Any(l2 =>l2.Equals(l1)));
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

It does what you told it: for every element in the list there is at least one enum value that does not equal that element.

What you probably wanted to do (selecting those that are not in the enum) is:

```
var result = lista.Where(l1 => Enum.GetNames(typeof(prova)).All(l2 => !l2.Equals(l1))).ToList()
```

finding the elements for which *all enum values are unequal*.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening with

```
Any(l2 => !l2.Equals(l1))
```

is that, you will always get `true`. Because your current element from `lista` will always be not equal to some element from your enum `prova`. Add a break point on  `!l2.Equals(l1)` and you will know more!

If you intend to get all the elements from `lista` except those in enum `provea` you should try

```
var enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(prova));
lista.Where(l1 => !enumNames.Contains(l1)).ToList().ForEach(l => Console.WriteLine(l));
```